# Authz file in svnserve

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, authz, svnserve

I am trying to setup the authz file in svnserve (under SUN OS). 
my repo name is CL_xyz, the repo path is /export/svnrepo/xyz.
How to specify the repo path at step x to get the desired result? Rightnow, i am getting an error -

```
Sending        test.txt
Transmitting file data .svn: E220001: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E220001: Access denied
svn: E220001: Your commit message was left in a temporary file:
```

**authz file**

```
[groups]
admin = app
# [/foo/bar]
# harry = rw
# &joe = r
# * =

[/branches]  ----step x
#[/]

#* = rw
@admin = rw
```

PS: my svnserve.conf and passwd files are working fine.

**svnserve.conf file**

```
anon-access = none
auth-access = write
password-db = passwd
authz-db = authz
realm = CL_xyz
```

Seeking for an expert to solve my tiny problem. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

So when you are authenticating with a user name of "app" and are able to read with that credential, for example, do an update?

You have only granted write access to the members of the admin group in the /branches path off the root path of your repository. I assume that is the path you are trying to write to? Perhaps if you show the svn command line you are using it would help.

Can you run svn info and show the output of that?